# Hash, encryption of file... key? Need help

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash, brute-force

So my previous question was with some help on pcap files as I am doing a security course and we have a challenge to figure out what was going on in our network. Now one of the files I retrieved is an encrypted file, not sure what type of encryption tho:
So I wonder if this might aid in decrypting the text file? The text file is much longer than what I have posted but any help on having a go or guess at this would be grateful.

Comment: It's obviously Base64 encoded and shows clearly visible patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded audio [RIFF/WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file.

First you need to Base64-decode it (for instance, with [YellowPipe's online tools](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/encrypter/index.php)) and you get <sup>*(sorry for the one-line ugly format)*</sup>:

```
RIFFº WAVEfmt U€>Ä  ´qfact€©data| ÿó8Ä[ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿó(Ä_[ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿó8Äš[ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ§^X$BÁ!a³33û¸ŽÂÇ5»ÂÏ9Île¯=‚ˆmÒ4üÊ1>CP–È3ó]ö™#H„‘ †‚då'¨eÎpÉÎ Z4hä@ †Ûƒsœ2ç°@Ââ‚üÎ1?Åð–È.sô€º„&#FÞÁD¸ “'=¨B{PËœàêË‘@ƒ ¾ä¢… 6€ Á&*AÂŸL¨23    Rq¹-Eœà  H£c”™ÓìoLJÊ",aÉ/ÿ2ŒOðì%².4v(¼2I¤òàÊ"’ëMÐBX=Êd2@ÐêÌ‹‡‰ty’n˜Ã’%ñØ;òYdXX3"‚DrÿÌãüŠ«f 1 ”0sdG¿ÿÔîƒ&ïÍìpÑÍ¤‹ÿý7M h³ü@Qä4c r(‚““K£O&#65533; ´’×mc    ájÖ¡†hóyºH  1A äÐÀ˜Âr)cÿÌ£L–I†Vi¤Šä¢q£‡Y?©iW=²öMæäûâSQÌÙÞtu‚a¡1åÂñÁ-‡›PöVÙ³x7±˜ö[üðÊßÿ3ŒG‚S/§Ýyµ€½Œî™íÏ5mOÊâ-ÿ7ÿÞÆ3gþÖÙüÁPµ:Œ%Kˆ>Å”Èbms É8ô/H   !¬e~£óÔ¹Ü¿“Äkvû×ìJÈ~gqñïïMö—¬ßÿÌ£h{6ØyÇ¾½­j‘zÜ5äH§k9vcya ·Ò46aûÎ¨õSø€µnë_ÿ`‰­ÓGX¨Þ‘ÿ3ŒAQ.Uü’€ÁX20Fq²7þJ$Ž…?8›VBÊÊsŒÞOÔaÆ?§¬™ÿä8"ŸÙ€ (þ´Uè„FeÖEKN[³Š8Yµú¿ßôífâa‘øÚò¹ÿÀ 7ÿó(Ä1Šå–C siõ}½sb4§A¦NÔXqNü««Èº‚ BbCK7J°A£ÀxƒŸë8fŠ¯v¡ÎèÿÌã@<;—OMˆ/ÿH®‹…IÍ„e-˜1éJÞ¯F3E’Y†Ö2ý›öå>UXP†ÊIˆè¶@    C   áÅÄ':2;12y…pÌ*JJ!|'’¼«Y íÅ¤C«]peÌ¿ûÿÌ£Ì@«™8AIñ·¸¸žÓöBñÈÿüp} Ÿ•ÉÌÏë&gu·Ñk¶Ð8åP!eLË!ZBœ mæaU¿˜Ëe:Îç{ÿÌã¸T‹9@Á*ðýþêAA7‘k¹¦Î £ÞÍŽØ„b®Å¥ÿô¥®ê(ýÈåvÇÔ-!<û=¡ÿ*n9 1ó™~ 'øÚÜæà2ö^Éh‚„†;)E0f§Nnêè2ÿó(Ä92æPFüŒðM(Z?ä´Žõƒnˆý7;d`/1Î”ƒ1 YŠš²>dÆŒÌÁå™Oü å{”(’ÿó8Ä0Â á’FüÌ<Ñ¸8=ZƒßÏyPçÐ Ó©Ò×”  pN ¶þiCûêH²>g¢»u8PÃIœ4£¶1MÚ>0ˆÂnÿí(—º, ^5¨bXuèÿ½,@B€yU^à_ÿ2ŒDÁîmh˜HC ¶ÝZ}jß9ÊVü§þ­{ŽÝpÎ†ÎrOÿÔ´Œªu:‹)F1†·3ÿDº:KÌüÎ1D ƒ´[¢ÁîQœQ:÷TÁ×ôÇ<x7ä)¨ttßF™Õ«T·SÍ™ÜŒ‹_àBeü²Ì•T…šªú?ý&´WÃ@p0:ÿ$¥5zžÞÄÚÑªØÿNÉêz°¸H_ÿÌ£ˆAÈ†ðe; Ào÷þÿÐÊT1P™ÝÁB‹‘Õÿýáÿï@Æ    ‚Ëk®?/Cñô`Íï’új.!öÿ3ŒEÁmF¨IÌ¾ÄÒHx>³„!-$‡!íI$µþ¦`1z &½ ›äL6ßÿýBäz0@¤ÄM˜ñ&.»w(j¨è“†ù­÷1I£õ›$ýK<I.fh’Ûu-þµÊ,)]€Ÿ/ÿÿó(Ä{AÒâ,h
```

You can see from the [header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_%28computing%29) that it's a [RIFF (.WAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file. I don't guarantee that the output above is entirely valid, as I'm not sure how trustworthy YellowPipe's tools are.

And unfortunately I don't have sound on this PC so I cannot listen to it!!

**EDIT:**

You mentioned in the question that you only provided an excerpt. Obviously, you'd need to reconvert base64-decode the whole file to work on something useful, not just an excerpt.

If possible, please post the whole file to Pastebin, Dropbox, Google Docs or something like this.

**EDIT 2:**

It works perfectly fine with your file.
It just doesn't work with YellowPipe because it outputs to the page and you probably damage the output when the browser uses a different encoding. Using a decoding program or another webservice like [MotoBit's Base64 Decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to send the output to a file gives you a valid binary file, which you can rename to a WAV file (e.g. `audio.wav`) and listen to it.

Do that and you can listen to the message.
Then I don't know what the Applecore key could be used for. It could be that a secret message is embedded in the file by steganography. I assume that's the trick.

Comment: i tryed changing the file type to see if it would play but got nothing...

Comment: @KirstyWhite: there might be other transformations to apply, and that we haven't found. I don't know.

Comment: @KirstyWhite: for instance, you mentiond a key in the question. Maybe you could experiment with that.

Comment: @KirstyWhite: hang on... you mentioned that the text file is much longer than what you have posted. Did you try to reconvert the whole file? Because I obviously did it only on the part you gave us, and that would obviously generate an incomplete file, which would explain why it wouldn't play.

Comment: Hey haylem yes I tried to convert the whole file, I wasnt sure if the file had just had its extension renamed so tryed wav, avi mp3 etc to see if it would play but no luck. So its defo encrypted. I will upload the file for you.

Comment: file link can be found in the question now. Hope you have some success. Rem that there was also the other text file that contained the Applecore hash. I shouldnt need to upload it as its just 32 bits long and is already in the question.

Comment: @KirstyWhite: tried with your file and it worked fine, see the edit. It's not encrypted. But maybe it contains a hidden message.

Comment: yeah thanks very much for the site worked great with me too! Ok really dont have a scooby what the hashed Applecore is for then?

Comment: @KirstyWhite: Just stumbled across that old question. I just realized, could be that the "applecore" hash meant to be used as a key to verify a DRM for the audio file? No clue, really. Just something that pops into my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the file looks like it's base64 encoded. I'd try looking at it in hex to see if there are any recurring structures/sequences that could hold metadata (e.g. the stuff in the beginning).

Then I'd download http://www.cryptool.org/en/ and give a few ciphers a try (trying both applecore and the hash as keys).

Comment: +1 to you as you had written your response while I was trying out several encodings. Hat tip.